# Should I get a new showerhead holder or replace the whole slider?

Tags: plumbing, shower

The showerhead holder component of our slider broke. I can see a few options online for replacement showerhead holders that will be fine if they work well. And I don't want to pay a lot to replace the whole slide if we can help it.

What's the best thing to do? Will a replacement showerhead holder work fine?

[image: the slide]

[image: the showerhead]

Comment: I think the critical dimension is the diameter of the slider rod. Get that right and you’ll be fine.

Comment: This is an answer and I'm happy to accept it if you were to add as an answer.

Comment: Written as an answer, but wait a bit before you checkmark it… someone might have a more thorough answer.

Comment: I think that's a fine answer.  Looks like an adjustable (18-25mm) holder can be had for less than a sawbuck on Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the critical dimension is the diameter of the slider rod. Get that right and you’ll be fine.